# How can I search/replace in block code of function only (Atom)?

Tags: replace, atom-editor

If I have a long function or object with nested objects and I want to be sure if a key/value is in there how can I search/replace only in this block of code (so I can change display: 1 to display: 0 everywhere inside a nested object for e.g)? I know how to search in files, how to exclude files or directories in global search but this is related to specific file and specific function/object inside it.

Basically is there any way to search/replace string from line X to line Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

1) To open the search replace tab press cmd+f or the equivalent in any other non- MacOS (control + f).

2) Then, on the right you will see only in selection option (2nd button from the right top corner in that tab). So you can select the long block of code and search/replace.